# PayPal payment showing as pending in hotel booking lite plugin on localhost

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, sandbox

I integrated PayPal into my hotel booking lite plugin, and payments are successfully transferred from my personal sandbox account to my business sandbox account. However, on my WordPress website running on localhost, the payment status remains pending, and I have to manually update it. I'm using a sandbox Business account for the merchant and a personal account for the user. I've tried various sandbox accounts, enabled the forced secure SSL option, and disabled the IPN verification option to specify an IPN listener for a specific payment. Can someone help me identify what I might be doing wrong?

What I tried and expected:
I have experimented with various sandbox accounts, checked the "forced secure SSL" option, and disabled the "IPN verification" option to specify an IPN listener for a specific payment. I expected the PayPal payments to be automatically reflected as completed on my WordPress website running on localhost, mirroring the successful transfers from my personal sandbox account to the business sandbox account.

What actually resulted:
Despite the successful sandbox transactions, the payment status on my WordPress website remains pending, and I have to manually update it to reflect the completed payment. I am seeking assistance in identifying the root cause of this issue and understanding why the automatic update is not occurring as expected.

Comment: The wordpress plugin you are using likely depends on a working IPN integration for the payment to move out of pending. There are API-based wordpress or woocommerce PayPal integration plugins that do not require IPN, try one of them.

Comment: Yes I know. What should I do for IPN integration?

Comment: not use anything that requires it, mainly. if you insist on using such things it's a bad use of your time for an inferior solution